# App failing to build on iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 (Swift)

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode

I am working on an iPhone app that includes a library for custom alert views. You can find the library [here](https://github.com/zelic91/ZAlertView). Everything has been implemented properly and the app runs flawlessly on iPhone 6, 6+, and s models as well. However, whenever I try and run the app on the iPhone 4/4s and iPhone 5/5s there are errors related to the alert view library. The current deployment target is 9.3

Here are the error codes that I get:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

---

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: If it is asking for i386 it is trying to build a simulator build. Where did you get the custom library? There are no guarantees a pre-built (if that is how you got it) has the architectures you need . You can always run `lipo` to find out the architectures in the lib. Example: `lipo -i mylib.a`.

Comment: The library is linked above. I have used it in the past without fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days of searching I have found a fix for this issue. Hold down `option` while cleaning your build. (located `product` > `clean`) in Xcode. This cleaned the build folder and now everything is working just fine!